# Facebook SDK Android App Release Crash

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to integrate Facebook Sign in in my android app. It works perfectly fine with the androiddebugkey. However, as per the guidelines at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/#release-key-hash, I have already generated the release key with the Keystore that I get when I generate Signed apk (*.jks file), and added this key to my Facebook App ID settings. Still, I get this exception "Invalid key hash. The key hash ***** does not match any stored key hashes. Configure your app key hashes at *****. Please help me solve this problem.
Thank you.

Comment: Call `Settings.getApplicationSignature(Context)` in your activity and log the value returned by the function. That is your keyhash value.  Are you signing your apk with the release key?

Comment: We haven't generated a signed apk with the Facebook Sign in integrated. I am using the signed apk that we created earlier because I need the path of the keystore to generate release key.

Comment: `The key hash ***** does not match any stored key hashes.` Replace the key hash in FB app with the one that facebook shows in the log.

Comment: But that would be a local key which would work only on those devices that get the apk file of the app from my laptop. If I copy the same code in another laptop, then the key changes, and then the same code would not work.

Comment: Thats why you need to add and sign with the same key everytime. There is no other option.

Comment: So, what you are suggesting is that I should generate a new signed apk for my application, and then use that *.jks file to create a new release hash key for facebook sign in and add this new key to my facebook app id settings. Am I right?